# GitHub project report from repository folder

Tags: git, github

I have GitHub repository named as **Projects**, which contains multiple project folders such as P1, P2 and p3. Each folder contains individual project files and I want to create a GitHub report page for each one of folder as

```
Username.github.io.Projects/P1
```

In general when a user want to publish repository, it is published as `username.github.io/repository`.

***How can I publish them individually as folder project report***

I somewhat want to replicate my project report as this [repository](https://github.com/davidventuri/udacity-dand) for reference which has multiple folders, which in turn has GitHub pages for each project separately, for example [Project P1 report](http://davidventuri.github.io/udacity-dand-p1/)

Can anyone explain how this guy has done it.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you would need one Git repo per folder (P1, P2, P3), each one could then be published in its own GitHub page.

You would then still be able to group those 3 folders/repos into one main project repo, using [Git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)

```
cd /path/to/main/repo
git submodule add -- /url/P1
git submodule add -- /url/P2
git submodule add -- /url/P3
git commit -m "Add P1, P2 and P3"
git push
```

> I  somewhat want to replicate my project report as this repository

This looks more like a [project page repo](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/#project-pages)

Comment: Thanks for your response. :)

I somewhat want to replicate my project report as this [repository](https://github.com/davidventuri/udacity-dand)

which has multiple folders, which in turn has github pages for each project separately, for example Project P1 [report](http://davidventuri.github.io/udacity-dand-p1/)

**Can you explain how this guy has done it.**